# Check if a word is real

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary

I am developing a Windows Phone app that requires users to type in valid words that would be in a standard English dictionary.  I'm a little confused, however, as to how to go about checking that a word is real. Does anyone know of a good dictionary API to interact with, or will I need to add a word list to my app as a text file?

Comment: Mac OS/iOS have a built-in spellchecker with a public API. Maybe Windows Phone has one too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/b2c2ee08-d28b-4bfa-8d89-4fd4301bf8cd) seems to indicate that the spell checking API is not exposed to the developer, although there is at least [one third party product](http://keyoti.com/products/rapidspell/silverlight/) that claims it provides an API-based solution (which also has an evaluation with which you can test how it works).

---

As to how you implement this feature if you cannot use a third party product, the problem with English is every other language :-) By that, I mean, it wasn't necessarily that consistent to begin with, and it has "lifted" words from dozens of other languages.

Hence there are no really decent *rules* that can tell you if a word is valid.

You'll need to maintain a dictionary and, given the bizarre corners of the language, you'll probably have to restrict it to common words (and, if space is an issue, short ones as well).

---

And, by the way, if you *do* go the self-written dictionary-based approach, you can use a little trick I learnt *many* years ago.

You can encode each word as:

- the number of characters (a byte) in common with the last; and
- the new ending.

So the word list

```
HERE            would encode as    THIS
-------------                      ----
sanctimonious                      0,sanctimonious
sanction                           6,on
sanguine                           3,guine
trivial                            0,trivial
```

You're saving 7 bytes straight up there (19%) and I suspect the saving would be similar for a 20,000 word dictionary just due to the minimum distances between (ie, common prefixes of) adjacent words.

To speed lookup, you can also maintain a 26-entry table in memory which held the starting offsets for words beginning with `a`, `b`, `c`, ..., `z`. The words at these offsets always will automatically have 0 as the first byte as they have no letters in common with the previous word.